# How should I modify the initial guess for normalised version of optimisation task?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am solving a large optimization problem. The problem contains 500 decision variables and few hundred constraints. Since the constraints are very tight and nonlinear, any random initial guess doesn't yield a solution. Fortunately I have a initial guess that can solve the problem. That initial guess was obtained by solving the problem in a dynamic simulation software.

The problem is , when I normalize the objective function (`[minF-F(X)]/Range`), the problem does not converge to a solution.
How should I modify the initial guess for normalized version of that problem?

**I am using matlab**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your requirement. You have a nonlinear optimization problem with an initial solution. What do you want do with that?

Comment: with that initial point I can solve the problem using `fmincon` . But when I normalise the function, this initial point doesn't work. @Nitish